# Access hashed value for iOS fingerprint?

Tags: android, ios, fingerprint

According to this website, it says there is a hashed value for fingerprints. Is there a way to access this hashed value? 
    http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/22/iphone-5s-fingerprint-sensor-gets-completely-misunderstood/

What about Android?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: The Apple wording does not say it saves a "hash* but rather a * mathematical representation* of the fingerprint which may be substantially more complex.

Answer (score 1):

> Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only
>   to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure
>   Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled
>   fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of
>   the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never
>   access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and
>   it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses
>   it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587